# Array.prototype.filter() passed as props trigger child's component to re-render but Array.prototype.sort() won't

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm using ReactJS, and would like to pass a filtered and sorted array into a component's props, as shown in the code snippet below:

```
<component arrayData={justAnArray
.filter(//some condition here)
.sort(//sorting function here)} />
```

The component is designed to update its state if the received props is different from the previous props, as shown below:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (this.props.arrayData != nextProps.arrayData){
        this.setState({ // some state here })
    }
}
```

This caused an error

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

During troubleshooting, I found that if the component is passed with only .sort() will not result in any error i.e.

```
<component arrayData={justAnArray
.sort(//sorting function here)} />
```

But the error will appear if only .filter is passed i.e.

```
<component arrayData={justAnArray
.filter(//some condition here)/>
```

This is strange, so I started to research on the differences between Array.prototype.sort() and Array.prototype.filter(). I found that [.filter() returns a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [.sort() seems to return the original array since the sorting is done in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Could this possibly be the reason causing the error? If yes what should I do to prevent this error?

Thank you.

---

EDIT: As per @Nandu Kalidindi's request, I'm posting the relevant code:

```js
class Pagination extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pager: {}
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // set page if items array isn't empty
    if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length) {
      this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // reset page if items array has changed
    if (this.props.items != nextProps.items) {
      this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
    }
  }

  setPage(page) {
    var items = this.props.items;
    var pager = this.state.pager;

    if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
      return;
    }

    // get new pager object for specified page
    pager = this.getPager(items.length, page, 3);

    // get new page of items from items array
    var pageOfItems = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);

    // update state
    this.state.pager = pager;

    // call change page function in parent component
    this.props.onChangePage(pageOfItems);
  }

  render() {
    return( //render )
  }
 }
export default Pagination;
```

This is basically a React Native version of [this ReactJS pagination example online](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/03/14/react-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google).

And this is how I use the component:

```js
  const someData= [{id: 1, title: 'a'}, 
  {id: 2, title: 'b'}, 
  {id: 3, title: 'c'}, 
  {id: 4, title: 'd'}, 
  {id: 5, title: 'e'},];
  
  class SomePage extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      pageOfItems: [],
    }

    this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    this.filterAndSort = this.filterAndSort.bind(this);
  }

  
  filterItems = (items) => {
    return items.filter(this.handleFilter);
  }

  sortItems = (items) => {
    return items.sort(this.handleSort);
  }

  filterAndSort = () =>{
    return this.sortItems(this.filterItems(someData));
  }
  
   onChangePage = (pageOfItems) =>{
    //update state with new page of alignItems
    this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
  }
  
    render(){
    
        return(

        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
                        {this.state.pageOfItems
                          .map((item) => {
                          return(
                            <box item={item} />
                            //just a component that displays the objects inside the arrays
                          )
                          })

                        }

                      </ScrollView>

                      <Pagination items={this.filterAndSort()} onChangePage={this.onChangePage} />
       )
   }
   
export default SomePage;
```

---

EDIT 2:

Just for the reference of other people, the answer to this question is not to compare array directly using '===' like I did. For more information please refer to @Nandu Kalidindi's answer.

Comment: That is strange, could you please try assigning state rather than using `setState`: Eg: `this.state.arrayData = nextProps.arrayData` and not `this.setState({arrayData: nextProps.arrayData})`?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi I tried it. It doesn't gives any error now, but the component does not display things as intended because the state is not updated properly I guess.

Comment: It's actually not required to `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps`. But did you check if your render is receiving the expected. Moreover you cannot just compare two arrays like that. It will always return `true`. `[1] != [1] is always true`

Comment: @Nandu Kalidindi the render is not as expected. Thanks for pointing out the logic expression which is something I always forget. However it does not seems to be the cause of the error.

Comment: The `render` method will get the correct state whichever you set in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Without the render method I too cannot say anything. Please try posting as much relevant code as possible.

Comment: The error mentions `componentWillUpdate()` and `componentDidUpdate()`. Have you defined those in your component? If so, please add them to your post. Otherwise, why do you think the problem is happening in `componentWillReceiveProps()`?

Comment: @AlienBishop That's a default React error whenever the component bounces between `render` and `setState`.

Comment: @Alien Bishop, to answer your question. The code originally indeed is using componentDidUpdate to setState. However I changed it to componentWillReceiveProps after found out the error. The error still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No need to `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps`, a mere assignment is sufficient. This is not the reason for infinite loop but just a good practice.
2. Never compare arrays like that. `[1] == [1] is always false`. Either use `JSON.stringify` or use this approach [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)
3. Now the reason why `filter` + `sort` is not working as opposed to just `sort` is because `filter` creates a new array which means a new reference, where as `sort` returns the same reference

Check the difference here.

```js
k = [1, 2, 3, 4]

r = k.sort()

console.log(k === r)
//TRUE

r = k.filter(elem => true).sort()

console.log(k === r)
// FALSE
```

So, when you are using `filter` + `sort` your component is constantly setting state irrespective of the condition you put, where as during `sort` it's always equal and state update never takes place.

Modify the snipper like below

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props.arrayData) != JSON.stringify(nextProps.arrayData)){
        this.state.arrayData = nextProps.arrayData;
    }
}
```

Now, why your component is re-rendering infinitely is another mystery, you must be setting state in your `componentWillUpdate` or `shouldComponentUpdate` hook. That is just my guess. Which is why I recommend you post all the relevant code that is there.

Comment: Wow, never knew that even though it appears to be the same arrays, but they are not === to each other. I will post the component code shortly, but it has around 200 lines. Do you have any suggestion how should I post it?

Comment: Just post the `render`, `componentWillUpdate`, 'shouldComponentUpdate` and any other callbacks to parent component.

Comment: The problem really is the method I used to compare array. Looking back to my code, in componentWillReceiveProps, I have used the condition this.props.items != nextProps.items to update the state, where the items is an array. Since I'm passing a filtered array into the component's props, this condition is always true as you mentioned above, which causes infinite loop of state updates. Thank you so much, wish you have a great day ahead!

Comment: You are most welcome. `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps` should not result in the infinite loop in theory but since you say everything works as expected, I am not going to check the code, its pretty long.